# Why does "Read only" mode also not provide cross-site functionality?

Tags: support, notification-bar, read-only

The site just came out of read only mode. I know why and when and all that from [the twitter feed](https://twitter.com/stackstatus), and this question isn't about that. Two things happen when the site is in "read only" mode that appear to be unrelated to read-onliness:

- the notification bar drop downs don't work. That is, if I go to a page that was logged in, and has lit up one or the other or both of the inbox/rep notifications, if I click them I do not get the dropdown showing my recent notifications and activity (I get an attempted dropdown that never loads.) If I move the hover over to "my sites" I get my sites. If I click one, that site then loads in read only mode.
- Once on a page displaying the read only mode banner there are no notifications, which  doesn't surprise me (they come back later) but I can't use the dropdown because it's behaving as though I am not logged in.

Is a better name for read-only mode "nobody is logged in" mode? Is this an important part of the failover process? Is it hard to let me navigate "my" sites or see my rep changes? Does keeping everyone logged out save the effort of looking up whether they've voted, or lighting up links for things like editing and flagging that they can't do anyway because everything's read-only?

I know it tends not to last long. But sometimes one site is down and another is up, and not being able to quickly navigate from a down site to an up site is an irritation. If there's a reason for it, it will be easier for me to shrug off the irritation. If there isn't, then perhaps some of this functionality can be provided even during failovers / successovers or whatever.